# How to properly implement IEnumerable to return item to be prioritize by a property?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable

My goal is to return the first `Foo` item from a list of foos that matches a `Boo` enum condition, and it should be prioritize by the `Boo` value as shown in the example, if none of the items matches the condition then just return the first item.

The model:

```
class Foo 
{
    E_Boo Boo { get; set; }
}
enum E_Boo
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Jessie = 1,
    Abby = 2,
    Felix = 3,
    Lacey = 4,
    Lucia = 5,
    Anisa = 6    
}
```

This is what I tried, it works:

```
    public Foo GetFooByBooPriority(IEnumerable<Foo> foos)
    {
        if(foos.Any(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Abby))
            return foos.First(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Abby);
        else if (foos.Any(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Lacey))
            return foos.First(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Lacey);
        else if (foos.Any(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Lucia))
            return foos.First(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Lucia);
        else if (foos.Any(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Felix))
            return foos.First(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Felix);
        else if (foos.Any(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Anisa))
            return foos.First(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Anisa);
        else if (foos.Any(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Jessie))
            return foos.First(x => x.Boo == E_Boo.Jessie);
        else
            return foos.First();
    }
```

Any Idea how to improve  this prioritize retriever in terms of performance and a cleaner code?

UPDATE:

In The prioritize logic needs to be decoupled from the enum `E_Boo` definition, in other words, If the enum definition will be changed, the prioritize logic should remain the smae.

Comment: `foos.OrderBy(x => x.Boo).FirstOrDefault()` ?

Comment: @vasily.sib looks like `foos.OrderBy(x => x.Boo.ToString())` would be a better match the the OP's code...

Comment: If the priorities are completely random (unlike your example) then an attribute against each enum entry with a priority in it is your best bet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654151/how-to-sort-enum-using-a-custom-order-attribute shows you how to do that.

Comment: @ShaharShokrani you may implement a `IComparer<E_Boo>` and pass it to `OrderBy`, like this: `foos.OrderBy(x => x.Boo, eBooComparerInstance).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: what you can do for performance reasons is to use a counting sort on your list -> (as long as the enum values are linear or when using flags then with only one bit per enum value), you can use the enum vlaue as an index position into an array of `Foo`  -> then after you went through the Ienumerable, just go through your list and return the first one that is not null. This should be O(n) and better than a normal sort of (O(n * log(n)))

Comment: What dolt removed my relevant comment about Enum.GetValues? Please read comments you are deleting..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to decouple the implementation from the enum values, and names

One simple solution would be to add a `List<E_Boo>` to your code and populate it in the order of the `E_Boo` values you want:

```
var booOrder = new List<E_Boo> 
{
    E_Boo.Abby,
    E_Boo.Lacey,
    E_Boo.Lucia,
    E_Boo.Felix,
    // ... And so on
};
```

And then sort the `IEnumerable<Foo>` by the index of the `E_Boo` value in that list:

```
var result = foos.OrderBy(f => booOrder.IndexOf(f.Boo)).First();
```

Comment: Indeed you would probably not use `IndexOf` (due to linear search) in actual code but as explanation it's perfect.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if it's a small enough amount of values to fit in an enum, I wouldn't expect any performance issues caused by the search algorithm being used. In terms of performance, I might want to try an array over a list, but I really don't think it should matter much in such cases. Thanks for your feedback, though :-)

Comment: If `booOrder` does get big, then using dictionary lookups would be better than doing a linear search with `IndexOf`. That optimization is probably not needed now though.

Comment: @RoadRunner I totally agree - but if an enum gets that big, that performance penalty is probably the least of your worries :-)